# {' '} - зачем это пишут в React JS после блока?

Tags: reactjs

Объясните зачем это нужно  . Иногда встречаю данное выражение.

Answer (score 3):

оно нужно, что бы вставить именно пробел - иногда строки склеиваются не там, где это нужно. На [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38547558/why-do-people-put-in-their-react-jsx) есть пример с объяснением.

```
<div>
 Text
 <a>some Text</a>
</div>
```

будет Textsome Text

```
<div>
 Text{' '}
 <a>some Text</a>
</div>
```

будет Text some Text

Comment: С примером было бы лучше)

Comment: Кстати, пропиши вопросу ассоциацию.

Comment: так я пример привел. или хочется ещё больше?

Comment: Ну мой поподробнее будет, к тому же запускаемый)

Comment: @Qwertiy ну-да ну-да https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdoYQ.png   :D

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, у тебя почему-то SO глючит. Вот, всё работает: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZV73S.png

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы между написанными на разных строках jsx-элементами вставилась текстовая нода с пробелом.

```js
ReactDOM.render(<div>
  <p>
    Следи за пробелами
  </p>
  <p>
    <span>Следи</span> <span>за</span> <span>пробелами</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span>Следи</span>
    {' '}
    <span>за</span>
    <span>пробелами</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <q> Следи за пробелами по краям </q>
  </p>
  <p>
    <q>
      Следи за пробелами по краям
    </q>
  </p>
  <p>
    <q>
      {' '}Следи за пробелами по краям{' '}
    </q>
  </p>
  <p>
    <q>
      {' Следи за пробелами по краям '}
    </q>
  </p>
</div>, document.querySelector('main'))
```

```css
p { white-apce: pre; font-family: monospace; }
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<main></main>
```